# Is a subring contained in the centralizer of its centralizer?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Fix a ring $B$. Given a subring $A \subset B$, we define$$A^! := \{b \in B : ab = ba,\text{ }\forall\,a \in A\},$$the centralizer of $A$ in $B$. This is a subring of $A$, so we can iterate $A^{!!} := (A^{!})^!,\text{ }A^{!!!} := (A^{!!})^!$, etc.

My question is, do we have an inclusion $A \subset (A^!)^!$? What is an example of a pair $A \subset B$ where inclusion is strict?

Comment: A side note: Theorems which provide sufficient conditions for $A=(A^!)^!$ to hold are called [double centralizer theorems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_centralizer_theorem).

Comment: Whenever the defining relationship of some set like this is symmetric, then you'll get that the original set is in the double application of your special operator. Another example is the annihilator operator for subsets in a commutative ring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply writing down the definition gives the answer. Let $a \in A$. Then by definition of $A^!$ (horrible notation by the way), for all $b \in A^!$, $ab = ba$. This precisely means that $a \in (A^!)^!$, and this was true for all $a \in A$, thus $A \subset (A^!)^!$.

Any strict subring of a commutative ring gives an example where the inclusion is strict, e.g. $\mathbb{Z} \subsetneq \mathbb{Q} = (\mathbb{Z}^!)^!$ (and here you see why the notation is not good, it's not clear what the $!$ means without knowing that I intended $\mathbb{Q}$ to be the ambient ring, in addition to conflicting with usual notations for [Koszul duals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Koszul_duality)).