# Stabilization of all even/odd terms of sequence of iterated centralizers.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

This is related to my previous question, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1418497/is-a-subring-contained-in-the-centralizer-of-its-centralizer).

Fix a ring $B$. Given a subring $A \subset B$, we define$$A^! := \{b \in B : ab = ba,\text{ }\forall\,a \in A\},$$the centralizer of $A$ in $B$. This is a subring of $A$, so we can iterate $A^{!!} := (A^{!})^!,\text{ }A^{!!!} := (A^{!!})^!$, etc.

What is the easiest way to see that there is a stabilization of all even, resp. odd, terms of the sequence of iterated centralizers, e.g. we have: $A^{!!!} = A^!$ and $A^{!!!!} = A^{!!}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are asking, basically, is why $A^!=A^{!!!}$, because after that you just repeatedly apply the $!$ operator to two equal sets, and you've shown $n$ applications of $!$ is the same as $n+2$ applications for $n\geq 1$.

I think you learned elsewhere that $X\subseteq X^{!!}$ for any set $A$ at all. Apply this fact to $A^!$.

On the other hand, this operator is order reversing in the sense that $X\subseteq Y$ implies $Y^!\subseteq X^!$. Apply this to $A\subseteq A^{!!}$.